# Combine INSERTED and DELETED in a trigger without using a JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an audit trail solution, which dumps the contents of the INSERTED or DELETED table in a trigger to XML, along with the current user, timestamp, etc. For inserts and updates, it logs the former, and for deletions it logs the latter.

However, in order to determine what has changed between two logs for the same record, I need to self-join on the audit table to get the previous record. This in itself does not work too badly, but performance would be greatly enhanced if I could log both data_from and data_to in the trigger.

The obvious solution is to use an inner join between INSERTED and DELETED for updates, but the problem with this is that these tables are not and cannot be indexed, so the database needs to do a full row-by-row hash in order to produce a result. Since, in an update trigger, the order in the INSERTED and DELETED records is identical, I can't help feeling that there must be some way I can combine these two tables horizontally without using a join and without using a cursor.

What I have already tried and what I know won't work:

1. Using ROW_NUMBER in a common table expression will not work - the CTE is not indexed
2. Inserting the contents of INSERTED and DELETED into temporary tables, indexing those and then using them in a join - This is one fallback option I have at present, if I can't find a better solution.
3. Using two cursors, one for INSERTED and one for DELETED - this is out of the question for performance reasons.
4. Joining with the audit trail table in the trigger to get the previous XML - also works, but not as well as 2 above, and since I have the data I need in the DELETED table, I can't help feeling that there must be something useful I can do with it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "the order in the INSERTED and DELETED records is identical". This is **not** always the case. You cannot rely on this so options 1 and 3 are non starters anyway. A possible other option would be to not use triggers at all but use `OUTPUT INSERTED.*, DELETED.*` directly in your `UPDATE` statement. This will return the before and after version of each row together without any need for a join.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Why on Earth would the include the records in INSERTED and DELETED in different orders? That was rhetorical question, but I'm willing to take your word for it. It just seems a bit of a bizarre thing to do. Adding an OUTPUT clause to every query in an already mature product is not really an option. That would involve changing literally hundreds of thousands of queries.

Comment: There is no "order" to any table because tables are unordered by definition. They have to be displayed on the screen in some order of course but that ordering is undefined unless ORDER BY is specified . You can't rely on the displayed order or write queries that use the displayed ordering in any meaningful way.

Comment: You say: "*..in order to determine what has changed between two logs for the same record..*".  Why do you need to do this in a trigger?  The only reason that I can think of is minimize the XML size by determining which columns were changed in an UPDATE (since technically, they're *all* changed in an INSERT or DELETE), but can't you just use COLUMNS_UPDATED() for that?

Comment: @Peter - Here are two examples on SQL Fiddle demonstrating this (note the different result ordering between the two). [Example 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64bb2/1) and [Example 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2d65/1)

Comment: "... but the problem with this is that these tables are not and cannot be indexed, so the database needs to do a full row-by-row hash in order to produce a result.". I can't help but feel that you're prematurely trying to solve problems that you don't have. Specifically, measure the thing you care about (i.e. i/o, cpu time, wallclock time) with and without the trigger in place over a "typical" workload and measure the difference. If, by way of percentage, it's just a couple, then forget about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) feature? It captures changes more effectively than a trigger can and it is an asynchronous background process which means there is minimal impact on the processes actually making the updates.

Comment: I have considered this. It is the right tool for the job, really, but is quite top-heavy compared with my XML solution. It also requires that the SQL Server Agent service be running, and the client in question refuses to do this because of the perceived security risk. Since the INSERTED and DELETED logs are stored in separate records anyway, I don't really gain anything that I don't already have.

Comment: I would go for a tabular solution like CDC every time in preference to XML, which sucks as far as data accessibility goes. I haven't tried this but I imagine I'm certain you can substitute SQL Agent for any other scheduler - your client is presumably using some other scheduler application to handle backups, maintenance and other tasks.

Comment: Although this is not the route I am going to take, I am accepting this answer as it is the right tool for the job. Ultimately CDC has the lowest impact on processing time. I'll include the solution I did use as a separate answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I eventually went for is to transfer the data in the `inserted` and `deleted` tables into indexed table variables, and then work with them from there. Performance is not as good as it would be with CDC, but is acceptable and linear, and time to market was considerably shorter. I wrote a code generator to generate the triggers, a sample of which I have included below:

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(OBJECT_ID('TR_su_type_code_audit_log')) > 1 RETURN

DECLARE @user_key INT, @tp INT = 0
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted) SET @tp += 1
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) SET @tp += 2

DECLARE @i TABLE (type_code_key int, audit_data VARCHAR(MAX), PRIMARY KEY (type_code_key))
DECLARE @d TABLE (type_code_key int, audit_data VARCHAR(MAX), PRIMARY KEY (type_code_key))

INSERT INTO @i SELECT type_code_key,
    (SELECT type_code_key, type_code_group, id, description, is_system_reserved, site_key, code_int, 
            code_str, image_index, image_filename FOR XML RAW('audit'))
FROM inserted

INSERT INTO @d SELECT type_code_key,
    (SELECT type_code_key, type_code_group, id, description, is_system_reserved, site_key, code_int, 
            code_str, image_index, image_filename FOR XML RAW('audit'))
FROM deleted


SET @user_key = dbo.f_get_current_user()

IF @tp = 2
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audit_trail (mod_type, mod_date, user_key, audit_rec_table, audit_rec_key, audit_rec_key_1, 
            audit_rec_key_2, is_delta, data_to)
    SELECT 'I', GETDATE(), @user_key, 'su_type_code', t.type_code_key, NULL, NULL, 0, audit_data
    FROM @i t
END ELSE IF @tp = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audit_trail (mod_type, mod_date, user_key, audit_rec_table, audit_rec_key, audit_rec_key_1, 
            audit_rec_key_2, is_delta, data_from)
    SELECT 'D', GETDATE(), @user_key, 'su_type_code', t.type_code_key, NULL, NULL, 0, audit_data
    FROM @d t
END ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audit_trail (mod_type, mod_date, user_key, audit_rec_table, audit_rec_key, audit_rec_key_1, 
            audit_rec_key_2, is_delta, data_to, data_from)
    SELECT 'U', GETDATE(), @user_key, 'su_type_code', t.type_code_key, NULL, NULL, 0, t.audit_data, d.audit_data
    FROM @i t INNER JOIN @d d ON (t.type_code_key = d.type_code_key)
    WHERE ISNULL(t.audit_data, '') <> ISNULL(d.audit_data, '')
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

My working solution is to put a unique column into the table, like an IDENTITY. And then join DELETED and INSERTED only on that unique column.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the INSERTED and DELETED tables are not indexed. When you're adding/updating a single row, then this is not a problem. However, when you're updating millions of rows, the server needs to do trillions of comparisons (literally) to join the two tables.